# A different type of iterative function

Tags: python

I would like to define a function that iterates a given logistic recurrence relation n times, I have defined functions which 'break' when the function has converged, but not like this.

```
def logistic(x0,r,n):
for i in (1,n-1):
    xi = r * x0 * (1-x0)
    print xi
    xi=x0
```

I know this is very bad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error is with the `for loop`.

It is not indented properly, and `(1, n-1)` builds a tuple with only two elements, `1` & `n-1`

Also, it is unclear how many times you want the loop to run. I'm assuming you want it to run `n` times. 
Then you can try this:

```
def logistic(x0, r, n):
    """function for doing logistic regression n times"""
    for i in range(n):
        xi = r * x0 * (1-x0)
        print(xi)
        # here if you reassign xi = x0 each time, then you'll get the same
        # result in each iteration. I'm assuming that is an error in your logic
        # and that you meant x0 = xi
        x0 = xi
```